# Show and Hide Features of layers openlayers 3

Tags: openlayers-3

I am trying to hide Feature of a layer from jason where I define the feature by category. I tried **Jonatas Walker** method but my code is different not working http://jsfiddle.net/jonataswalker/z10de36z/ but my code is different so not working

Below is my json

```
{
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
          "name": "Missing Person",
          "src": "resources/icon.png",
          "category": "cat1"
      },
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [-0.45755, 51.507222]
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
          "name": "Wanted",
           "src": "resources/icon.png",
           "category": "cat1"
      },
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [-0.12755, 52.507222]
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
          "name": "Missing 1",
           "src": "resources/Blue_pointer.png",
           "category": "cat2"
      },
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [-1.12755, 52.507222]
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
          "name": "Wanted 3",
          "src": "resources/icon.png",
          "category": "cat1"
      },
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [-2.12755, 53.507222]
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
          "name": "Wanted 7",
          "src": "resources/icon.png",
          "category": "cat1"
      },
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [-0.1287, 53.507222]
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
          "name": "Wanted 9",
          "src": "resources/Blue_pointer.png",
          "category": "cat2"
      },
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [-3.12755, 50.907222]
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
          "name": "Missing 8",
          "src": "resources/Blue_pointer.png",
          "category": "cat2"
      },
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [-3.12755, 51.907222]
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
          "name": "Missing 18",
          "src": "resources/Blue_pointer.png",
          "category": "cat2"
      },
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [-4.12755, 51.907222]
      }
    }    
  ]
}
```

Openlayer code

```
var styleFunction1 = function(feature) {
                var styles = {
                    'Point': [
                    new ol.style.Style({
                        image: new ol.style.Icon({
                          src: feature.get('src'),
                          anchor: [0.5, 1]
                      })
                    })],
                    'LineString': [
                    new ol.style.Style({
                        stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
                          color: 'gray',
                          width: 5
                      })
                    })]
                };
                return styles[feature.getGeometry().getType()];
            };
vector = new ol.layer.Vector({
  source: new ol.source.Vector({
   projection : 'EPSG:4326',
   format: new ol.format.GeoJSON(),
   url: 'resources/multipoint.geojson'
 }),
  style: styleFunction1
});

map = new ol.Map({
              target: target,
              layers: [bingMapsRoad,myPetrolPlan,vector],
                view: new ol.View({
                    center: ol.proj.transform([-0.12755, 51.507222], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857'),
                    loadTilesWhileAnimating: true,
                    loadTilesWhileInteracting: true,
                    zoom: 6
                  }),
                controls: ol.control.defaults({ attribution: false }),
                loadTilesWhileInteracting: true
              });
```

To Hide I am trying something like

```
hideVectorLayer: function () {
    var abc = ConnectWebMap;
     var featureCount = vector.getSource().getFeatures();
     var featureCat = feature.get('category');
   console.log(featureCat);
    featureCount.forEach(function(feature) {
     if(feature){
      if(featureCat == 'cat1'){
      console.log('a');
  }
}
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can remove from the [VectorSource](http://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/ol.source.Vector.html) using **removeFeature** method

Answer (score 0):

you can make another layer ( a temporary one ) where you copy the features from the desired category and display it while setting the visibility of your main layer to false:

```
var tmp=new ol.layer.vector({ source : new ol.source.Vector()});
hideVectorLayer: function () {
  var abc = ConnectWebMap;
  var featureCount = vector.getSource().getFeatures();
  var featureCat = feature.get('category');
  console.log(featureCat);
  featureCount.forEach(function(feature) {
    if(feature){
      if(featureCat == 'cat1'){
        tmp.getSource().getFeatures().push(feature);
      }
    }
  });
  tmp.setStyle(vector.getStyle()); // set the same style to the tmp layer
  map.addLayer(tmp);// add it to the map
  vector.setVisible(false); // set the vector layer visibility to false
}
```

Comment: Added my code in your answer..  Its giving me Cat1 value from xyz variable now how to remove xyz(getting 'cat1') only.

Comment: I don't get what you want to do with it, and I think that edit should go in the question not in the answer